# Dynamically setting css variables using the style attribute doesn't work, Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, styles

I am trying to pass value to an animation from the style attribute, but the dynamic setting of the value does't work. 
I am using as a reference the following article https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/

HTML:

```
      <div class="labelContainer">
        <p #label class="optionLabel" [ngClass]="{'optionLabel--animated': isSelected(option) && checkOverflow(label)}"
         [style]="labelOffset" >
          {{ option.label }}
        </p>
      </div>
```

TS:

```
  _labelOffset = `--labelOffset: '0px'`

  checkOverflow(label):boolean {
    if(label.offsetWidth < label.scrollWidth){
      let offset = label.scrollWidth - label.offsetWidth;
      this._labelOffset = `--labelOffset: '${offset}px'`;
      return true;
    }
      return false;
  }


  get labelOffset(){
    return this._labelOffset;
  }
```

CSS:

```
.optionLabel{
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;

  &--animated{
    animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
    overflow: visible;
  }

  $labelOffset: var(--labelOffset);

  @keyframes marquee {
    0%{transform: translateX(0%);} 
    100% {transform: translateX($labelOffset);}
   }
}
```

Compiled HTML:

```
<p _ngcontent-qfr-c26="" class="optionLabel optionLabel--animated" ng-reflect-klass="optionLabel" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="">very long text</p>
```

I have tried to use DomSanitizer when passing the value but this doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best example is

https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/
https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript

Try this.

give your valiable in style.scss global file

```
:root {
--labelOffset:0px;
}
```

in your component ts file how to get variable value

```
let _labelOffset = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--my-variable-name');
```

Comment: let _labelOffset = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('----labelOffset');

Comment: sorry the above code is correct I forgot to update the variable in getpropertyvalue